# python make multiple lists of one list

Tags: python, python-3.x, list, python-2.7

in `PYTHON` i have one `list` and i want to make from it a **multiple** **lists**, for every **item** i want him to **create** a **list** with the **other items**

my initial list :

```js
cities = ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']
```

then i want the output to be :

```js
[
  ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1'],
  ['Chevalley','El Madania'],
  ['A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']
]
```

Comment: itertools might help you out. https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.combinations look at this documentation

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get all possible combinations of a list’s elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/464864/how-to-get-all-possible-combinations-of-a-list-s-elements)

Comment: @ilyesBourouba Let me know, what do you think of my answer. Now I am planning to delete my answers which are not useful for the question (No upvotes answers)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The below code will help you to create the resultant list you are looking for:

```
items = ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']
res = [[items[i],items[j]] for i in range(len(items)) for j in range(i+1, len(items))]
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
result_list = []
for i in ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']:
    for j in ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']:
        if i != j:
            result_list.append([i, j])
```

It should iterate over every possible pairing while ignoring pairing element with itself.

Answer (score 0):

while this isn't the same it is pretty close to what you are looking for.

```
import itertools
a = ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']
result = list(itertools.combinations(a,2)) # number is the amount of items you want in the resultant tuple
```

result will have tuples of length `2` in a list.

Answer (score 0):

Below should do it:

```
l  = ['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']
n = [[l[i], l[j]] for i in range(0, len(l) - 1, 1) for j in range(i + 1, len(l), 1)]
```

`n` will equate to:

```
[['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1'],
 ['Chevalley', 'El Madania'],
 ['A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']]
```

Answer (score 0):

nested for loops does your work

```
list1 =['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']

output =[]

for i in range(len(list1)):
 for j in range(i+1,len(list1)):
  output.append([list1[i],list1[j]]) 

print(output)#[['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1'],['Chevalley','El Madania',['A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania']]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use itertools and convert the output tuples into lists:

```
import itertools

new = [ list(el) for el in itertools.combinations(['Chevalley', 'A.Gharmoul 1', 'El Madania'], 2) ]
```